# Making CSV upload file faster (mysql - php)

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, csv, upload

I'm trying to upload a CSV file which contain more than 100k rows. The code below is working fine, but, it's too slow, i had to modify the php.ini 'cause of that. I'm looking for a way to make it faster.

```
    mysqli_query($db, "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
    mysqli_query($db, "BEGIN");
    mysqli_query($db, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
    fgets($handle); 
    $data = '';
```

`while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ';')) !== FALSE):
  $nf = trim($data[0]);
  //ignore values lower than 1
  if ($nf &lt 1):
   continue;
  else:
   $v1 = trim($data[1]);
   $v2 = trim($data[2]);

   $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_venda WHERE nota = ". $nf ;
   $rs = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   validaQuery($db, $rs);

   //if $nf alrealdy exists, update, else, insert a new row
   if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) &gt; 0):
    //UPDATE
   else:
    //INSERT
   endif; 

  endif;
 endwhile;

 mysqli_query($db, "COMMIT");
 mysqli_query($db, "SET AUTOCOMMIT=1");
 mysqli_query($db, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
 mysqli_close($db);
</pre>
<p>Does anyone know how can i make it faster?</p>`

Comment: why not a `load data infile ...` in mysql directly? Or use a `insert ... on duplicate key` so you're not running a select for every row you insert?

Comment: i have to treat each field in csv because there's a lot of spaces and other stuff, and, there'll more people uploading theses files, so i don't want them to direct access myadmin.